# squid url_rewrite_program excemption

Tags: acl, squid

Is there any way to limit url_rewrite_program? For example, I have a group of domains I will exclude from passing through url_rewrite_program.

Let's say I have ACL that always allows Yahoo, Google, Facebook and I don't want them to pass through the url_rewrite_program. Is that possible? Below is my configuration:

```
###################################
acl good_url dstdomain "/etc/squid/good-sites.txt"
http_access allow good_url

url_rewrite_program /var/myRedirector
redirect_children 10
redirect_rewrites_host_header off
##################################
```

In url_rewrite_program I wish to exclude good_url passing thourgh my redirector since it is already satisfied with the acl. Or what is the correct configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
url_rewrite_access allow !good_url
```